# using "payable" even when we do not send ETH?

Tags: solidity, tokens, payable, payments

When we want to send some `ETH`, we need to use the "`payable`" keyword. However, even when we want to send some `tokens` (i.e. `uint256 token`), we need to use again the "`payable`" keyword in our function as follows ? **or we can remove it** ?

```
struct AssetStruct {
        address owner;
        bool isOwner;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => AssetStruct) assetStructs;
    uint256[] public assetList;   
    mapping(address => uint) public balance;
    mapping(uint256 => mapping (address => mapping(address => bool))) public isPaymentDoneMutual;

function playerPaymentMutual(uint256 _id, address _player, uint256 _token)  payable public  returns(bool isIndeed) {

                address _owner;

                _owner = assetStructs[_id].owner;

                balance[_owner] = balance[_owner] + _token;

                balance[_player] = balance[_player] - _token;

                isPaymentDoneMutual[_id][_player][_owner] = true;

                        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `payable` when transferring tokens.

There are basically two reasons for this:

1) You are not transferring Ethers

2) Tokens are not transferred directly. They don't move from your wallet to another wallet as such - the transfer is performed by calling the token contract which just shuffles numbers internally (changes the `balances` variable contents)

Comment: Thank you. And in case of using `payable`, when we are only sending `token`, this may cause some problems ? (I mean in my function, it's better to remove it ? or I **have to** remove it ?) Thanks

Comment: You don't *have* to remove it, but unless you want to allow incoming Ether for that function you should remove it. The more you restrict what people can do with your contract the less chance there is for them (and for you) to screw up the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use `payable` modifier to allow your function to accept ether. This is not necessary to send ethers.

Hope this helps.